# Show remaining time for a macro

Tags: excel, vba

The below code runs through each line of data and deletes an Outlook appointment if the conditions are met. It also displays a progress bar updating when each row is processed, and then a msgbox saying how long it has taken - is there any way that I can get this to show the time remaining  on the progress bar or even the status bar also?

```
Sub DeleteAfterResponseCoring()

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim wb              As Workbook
Dim ws              As Worksheet
Dim objOutlook      As Outlook.Application
Dim objNamespace    As Outlook.Namespace
Dim objFolder       As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objAppointment  As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Set objOutlook = Outlook.Application
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
Set oItems = objFolder.Items
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String

'Remember time when macro starts
  StartTime = Timer


Dim r As Long
Dim pctdone As Single
r = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

'(Step 1) Display your Progress Bar
ufProgress.LabelProgress.Width = 0
ufProgress.Show
For i = 3 To r
'(Step 2) Periodically update progress bar
    pctdone = i / r
    With ufProgress
        .LabelCaption.Caption = "Processing Row " & i & " of " & r & vbCrLf & "Close window when complete."
        .LabelProgress.Width = pctdone * (.FrameProgress.Width)
    End With
    DoEvents
        '-------



For j = oItems.Count To 1 Step -1

    If (ActiveSheet.Name) = "Coring" And ws.Cells(i, 11).Value = "N/A" And ws.Cells(i, 8).Value = "Yes" Then
    ws.Cells(i, 15) = "Yes"
        Set objAppointment = oItems.Item(j)
        With objAppointment
            If .Subject = "Send reminder email - LBR " + ws.Cells(i, 3).Value Or .Subject = "FINAL DEADLINE - LBR " + ws.Cells(i, 2).Value Then
                objAppointment.Delete
            End If
            End With
            End If
Next j
Next i

If i = r Then Unload ufProgress

'Determine how many seconds code took to run
  MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

'Notify user in seconds
  MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Unless you know exactly how long a progress will take.. how will you know how much time is left? If we knew how to look into the future, we'd all be rich

Comment: A method to do display time is to make predictions. This relies heavily on maths. I'd check at every nth iteration how long it has taken to process that amount of rows, and calculate an average. If you know how many iterations have yet to come, you can use the calculated average to predict a remaining processing time

Comment: Tim is right, and as you know how much time has elapsed, you could start saving this information to build a mathmatical model of estimated time left. The more samples you gather, the better you estimation will become.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematicians will probably laugh at this, there might be an easier way.. but try adding this line inside your loop:

`Application.Statusbar = Round(((Timer - StartTime) / pctdone) - (Timer - StartTime), 0) & " seconds remaining."`

Simply put, it takes the amount of time so far and divides it by the percentage complete to calculate an estimated completion time, which can be used to work out how long is left. I think.

Once complete, you'll need to set `Application.Statusbar = False`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution so I ended up making a class to estimate time remaining. It is just a simple linear extrapolation and you can specify how far back to use as the sample in the estimate. To use it, add a class called `TimeRemaining` and add this code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Observations() As Variant

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim Observations(0)
    Me.AddObservation 0

End Sub

Public Sub AddObservation(Percentage As Single)
    Dim NewObservation(1)
    NewObservation(0) = Percentage
    NewObservation(1) = Timer
    
    ReDim Preserve Observations(UBound(Observations) + 1)
    Observations(UBound(Observations)) = NewObservation

End Sub

Public Property Get RemainingTimeEstimate(Optional Offset As Long = 1)
    'The offset is how many past observations you want to base the time estimate on.
    Dim Observation1
    Dim Observation2
    
    If Offset + 1 > UBound(Observations) Then
        Offset = UBound(Observations) - 1
    
    End If

    Observation1 = Observations(UBound(Observations) - Offset)
    Observation2 = Observations(UBound(Observations))
    
    Dim PercentageBetweenObs As Single
    Dim TimeBetweenObs As Single
    Dim PercentRemaining As Single
    TimeBetweenObs = Observation2(1) - Observation1(1)
    PercentageBetweenObs = Observation2(0) - Observation1(0)
    PercentRemaining = 1 - Observation2(0)

    'RemainingTime = ( Percentage remaining / Percentage observed ) * Observation Time
    RemainingTimeEstimate = Round(TimeBetweenObs * PercentRemaining / PercentageBetweenObs, 0)
End Property
```

Initialise the class in the code you want to estimate the time remaining for. Presuming your code has some loop you want to time, call `AddObservation` periodically and pass it the percentage (as a decimal) that is complete. Then to to get the time remaining estimate in seconds, call `RemainingTimeEstimate`. Here's an example usage, using mod 10 to update every 10th loop:

```
Sub TestTimeRemaining()
    Dim k As Long
    Dim Total As Long
    Total = 100
    Dim TimeRemainingEstimate As TimeRemaining
    Set TimeRemainingEstimate = New TimeRemaining
    
    For k = 1 To Total
        
        If k Mod 10 = 0 Then
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))
            Dim PercentageComplete As Single
            PercentageComplete = k / Total
            TimeRemainingEstimate.AddObservation PercentageComplete
                        
            Debug.Print "Time remaining: " & TimeRemainingEstimate.RemainingTimeEstimate(3) & "s"
        
        End If
        
    Next k

End Sub
```